# How can I bind the font size in a textBox to a data source?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've instantiated a class 'my_font_size' which has an accessor 'Size_Points', which I'm trying to bind across several controls.

This is what I'm trying:

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Font.Size", my_font_size, "Size_Points", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

But I get an Argument.Exception,

```
Cannot bind to the property 'Font.Size' on the target control.
```

How do I drill down to the property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Binding` in `winforms` does not support nested path, you have to bind the `Font` property and use some `Format` event handler to control the binding like this:

```
Binding bind = new Binding("Font", my_font_size, "Size_Points");
bind.Format += (s,e) => {
   var b = s as Binding;
   var currentFont = b.Control.Font;
   e.Value = new Font(currentFont.FontFamily, 
                      (float) e.Value, currentFont.Style);
};
textBox1.DataBindings.Add(bind);
```

However I doubt that your class `my_font_size` doesn't have enough condition to make the `Binding` work. Here is how it should be done by following the pattern to notify changes of some property:

```
public class my_font_size {
   float size_Points;
   public float Size_Points {
     get { return size_Points;}
     set {
        if(size_Points != value){
          size_Points = value;
          OnSize_PointsChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
     }
   }
   public event EventHandler Size_PointsChanged;
   protected virtual void OnSize_PointsChanged(EventArgs e){
     var handler = Size_PointsChanged;
     if(handler != null){
        handler(this, e);
     }
   }
}
```

You can also use `INotifyPropertyChanged` but I let that part for you to search more.

Comment: Note: Format is an event that fires when the property of a control is bound to a data value, and gives you access to modify the format of the items being bound. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `my_font_size` a `Font` instead and bind to the `Font` of the `TextBox`. The `Font` class is immutable and must be bound to holistically.

Comment: What is meant by "bound holistically"?

Comment: @sab669, you can't bind (i.e. `set`) any of its members. Therefore, you need to bind to the entire `Font` instead.

Comment: Oh, I guess I knew that. Just didn't know the term. Like you can't just set Bold to be true or false, you'd have to make a new Font object with the proper Bold state and set it to that?